# jenkins pipeline - Provisioning with CloudFormation

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation

[Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) talks about provisioning Docker containers.

[Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/integrating-ansible-jenkins-cicd-process) can be used for environment provisioning with Jenkins.

Using [pipeline script](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) , I would like to provision an AWS EC2 instance on AWS cloud using AWS CloudFormation template

Can Jenkins [pipeline script](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) reuse CloudFormation templates for provisioning on AWS cloud?

Comment: if you can do CloudFormation templates provisioning in your local terminal/cmd then Jenkins can do it as well

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the Jenkins pipeline for provisioning resources on cloud. You can store ur cloudformation code either in SVN or GIT and write a script to pull those resources from SVN and GIT and provision resources using "aws cli" commands in the script you create and use to deploy resources to cloud.

You can create separate jobs for different stages of pipeline and make it work.